# Excel VBA Remove Duplicates Reiteration vs Filter

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that contains ~8000 rows which have already been filtered.  I am trying to get a collection of values from a worksheet column with the duplicates removed.  Reading through the post here there are two ways to do this.  Loop through the collection and copy to a new collection if the value does not already exist in the new collection.
Or copy the data in the column to a temporary spreadsheet, filter and copy the the data to another column and then add it to the collection.

When dealing with a large amount of data the copy filter has the best performance but is clunky since a new worksheet has to be created.

I have not seen it but is there a way to do the copy filter in memory instead of creating a worksheet to do this?

**Reiteration:**

```
Sub GetColumnValues(Ws As Worksheet, Column As Long, CollValues As Collection)

Dim RowIndex As Long

    For RowIndex = 1 To GetLastRow(Ws)
        If CollValues.Count = 0 Then
            CollValues.Add (Ws.Cells(RowIndex, Column).Value)
        Else
            If IsInCollection(CollValues, Ws.Cells(RowIndex, Column).Value) = False Then
                CollValues.Add (Ws.Cells(RowIndex, Column).Value)
            End If
        End If
    Next RowIndex

End Sub
```

**Filter and Copy:**

```
Sub GetColumnValues(Ws As Worksheet, Column As Long, CollValues As Collection)

Dim rowLast As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim tmpWS As Worksheet
Dim tmpWsName As String

    tmpWsName = "TempWS"

    Call DeleteWs(TsWb, tmpWsName)

    Set tmpWS = TsWb.Sheets.Add()
    tmpWS.Name = tmpWsName

    rowLast = GetLastRow(Ws)

    Ws.Range(Ws.Cells(1, Column), Ws.Cells(rowLast, Column)).Copy
    tmpWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    rowLast = GetLastRow(tmpWS)
    tmpWS.Range(tmpWS.Cells(1, 1), tmpWS.Cells(rowLast, 1)).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=tmpWS.Range("B1"), _
        Unique:=True

    rowLast = GetLastRow(tmpWS)

    For Each c In tmpWS.Range(tmpWS.Cells(1, 2), tmpWS.Cells(rowLast, 2))
        If Len(c.value) > 0 Then
            CollValues.Add (c.value)
        End If
    Next c

    Call DeleteWs(TsWb, tmpWsName)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know why it has to be a collection, but to get an array fast having all values without doubles (of filtered list) you could do it like this: (pretty close to your first example)

```
Function GetColVal(Ws As Worksheet, Column As Long) As Variant
  Dim runner As Variant, outputVal() As Variant, i As Long
  ReDim outputVal(Ws.Range(Ws.Cells(1, Column), Ws.Cells(GetLastRow(Ws), Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count)
  For Each runner In Ws.Range(Ws.Cells(1, Column), Ws.Cells(GetLastRow(Ws), Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If i = 0 Then
      outputVal(0) = runner.Value: i = 1
    Else
      If IsError(Application.Match(runner.Value, outputVal, 0)) Then outputVal(i) = runner.Value: i = i + 1
    End If
  Next
  ReDim Preserve outputVal(i - 1)
  GetColVal= outputVal
End Function
```

the `Application.Match` is one of the fastest functions in VBA while `IsInCollection` can be extremely slow... better run a `For Each ...` loop to add everything in a collection than checking the collection...

```
Dim a As Variant
For Each a in GetColVal(Worksheets("SheetX"),7)
  MyCollection.Add a
Next
```

should be much faster than your examples... still i recommend not using collections particularly if you just use values... better use the `GetColVal`-array directly if possible...
`variantVariable = GetColVal(Worksheets("SheetX"),7)` then use the variant-variable for whatever you want to do (you also could paste it directly somewhere in a sheet)

a simple output into a worksheet would be like that:

```
Dim a As Variant
a = GetColVal(Worksheets("Sheet1"),13) 'values from sheet1 column M
'pasting in one row (starting at A1 in Sheet2)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, ubound(a) + 1)).value = a
'pasting in one column (starting at C5 in Sheet4)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range(Cells(5, 3), Cells(ubound(a) + 5, 3)).value = Application.Transpose(a)
```

**EDIT**

To show something different:

```
Function GetColumnValues(ws As Worksheet, Column As Long) As Range
  With ws
    Dim srcRng As Range, outRng As Range, runRng1 As Range, runRng2 As Range, dBool As Boolean
    Set srcRng = .Range(.Cells(1, Column), .Cells(GetLastRow(ws), Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each runRng1 In a
      If outRng Is Nothing Then Set outRng = runRng1
      For Each runRng2 In outRng
        If Intersect(runRng1, runRng2) Is Nothing Then
          If runRng2.Value = runRng1.Value Then dBool = True: Exit For
        End If
      Next
      If dBool Then dBool = False Else Set outRng = Union(outRng, runRng1)
    Next
  End With
  Set GetColumnValues = outRng
End Function
```

With this function you will get a range of all the cells which can be selected or copied to another location (with formating and everything else). Still you can add all elements into a collection with a `For Each ...`. I also not used `Match` to avoid the "Len > 255"-error

Comment: The only reason for the collection is that I am removing additional data after I remove the duplicate from outputVal.  It was easier to use the collection instead of redim a new array.  The only other way I can think of is to create a separate index array of what needs to be removed and then do the redim and copy to the new array all at once.

You have given me some ideas though thank you.

Comment: I am still looking into this.  One issue I found is that if a Variant array has a string in it longer than 255 characters the Application.Match fails with a type Mismatch error.  If I change my output array to a string array then I am able to process the entire data range.

Comment: @SteveP65 I added another function you may want to try (should be faster, but i can't tell for sure)... obviosely you will get a range which holds some benefits you may want to use later :)

Comment: I converted everything over to arrays and its much quicker.  I copied the range into an array and using the idea you suggested `ReDim Preserve outputVal(i - 1)` I was able to get my resultant array without the duplicates.  Since I was comparing two arrays I did not try to use the `Intersect(runRng1, runRng2)` function. I reiterated through the array to find the duplicates.

Comment: @SteveP65 If you are able to improve your own coding, the mission of SO is accomplished. If you run into trouble again, feel free to come back and ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just make arrays, then check against the arrays, then deliver your results back to the worksheet. Personally I like to do things in memory instead of through the Application IDE.

It is much faster (especially with tens of thousands of rows), you don't have to worry about screen refreshing, or having your user wonder what is going on with everything moving around so fast. I usually handle everything in memory, hand it back, then activate the worksheet that I want the user to see.

```vb
dim set1Array() as String
dim set2Array() as String
dim set1Rows as Long
dim set2Rows as Long
dim lngX as Long
dim lngY as Long
dim blnDebug as Boolean; blnDebug = true ' flag for debugging

' get count of rows so we know how big to make the arrays
set1Rows = GetLastRow(Ws1)
set2Rows = GetLastRow(Ws2)

' set arrays to the proper size
redim set1Rows(set1Rows - 1, 1)' 1 represents 2 columns since it's 0 based. the second column is a flag for duplicated.
redim set2Rows(set2Rows - 1, 0)' 0 represents 1 column since it's 0 based

' load the arrays with the sheet data
for lngX = 1 to set1Rows
  set1Rows(lngX - 1, 0) = Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A" & lngX).Text
next lngX

for lngX = 1 to set2Rows
  set2Rows(lngX - 1, 0) = Worksheets("Sheet2").range("A" & lngX).Text
next lngX

' I like to do a debug callout here to see what I got to make sure that I am good to go with the dataset
if blnDebug then
  for lngX = 0 to Ubound(set1Rows)
    debug.print "set1Rows(" & lngX & ") - col1: " & set1Rows(lngX, 0)
  next lngX

  for lngX = 0 to Ubound(set2Rows)
    debug.print "set2Rows(" & lngX & ") - col1: " & set2Rows(lngX, 0)
  next lngX

end if

' now do your comparison

for lngX = 0 to Ubound(set1Rows)
  for lngY = 0 to Ubound(set2Rows)
    if set1Rows(lngX, 0) = set2Rows(lngY, 0) then
      set1Rows(lngX, 1) = "1"
    end if
  next lngY
next lngX

' now your duplicates are flagged in the set1Rows array

for lngX = 0 to Ubound(set1Rows)
  if set1Rows(lngX, 1) = "1" then
    ' code for duplicated
  else
    ' code for unique
  end if
next lngX
```

Comment: The comparison is being done on one column of data.  So Ideally I would want to copy the column to an array, within that array remove any duplicate values.  I would then use that array for additional processing.